# Gratis, portable app to get text from a Windows control which does not support copy

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I need to get the text from a StringGrid, but the app won't let me copy.

My company won't let me install any software at all, so I am looking for a portable (and gratis) solution.

Comment: Did you try AHK? Should be possible with that in a way or another